# Running rake test and Rails 'cannot load such file -- rails/performance_test_help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-test

I am trying to run a rake test and I am unable to do it.  I keep getting this error:
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails/performance_test_help

I would greatly appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 17):

[`rails/performance_test_help`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.21/railties/lib/rails/performance_test_help.rb) is an old test helper that was used up to Rails 3.2 [for performance testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html). It was supposed to be required by performance test cases.

The file was remove in Rails 4 since the performance testing feature was extracted from Rails core and moved to the [rails-perftest](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails-perftest) gem.

If you are using Rails 4, make sure the gem is listed in your `Gemfile`, and it's correctly installed. If you don't use the feature, simply drop the performance test cases.

To lookup the offending file, simply search your project codebase for any `require 'rails/performance_test_help'` statement, and either fix the issue or remove the offending file if you don't need the performance test case.

Comment: That helps explain the issue, but I am still having trouble implementing the solution.  I installed the rails-perftest gem, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: You are correct in the assumption that I don't really know what they are; I am not an expert, nor a novice, I am pretty new to Rails, so I apologize for my lack of knowledge.  I would love to wipe out the performance test out if I knew exactly where to look for them.

Comment: Follow my instructions, search your codebase for that string, and delete the test case file. Also read the articles I linked to have an idea how a performance test case looks like. I can't tell you exactly what to delete, because the files can have any name.

Comment: I figured it out. I was not deleting the entire file, just the line of code in the file.  When I removed the file itself everything worked.  Thanks for you help, sorry for trouble.

Comment: If you remove that line, an attempt to run the file will likely cause a crash. If you don't use the file, delete it entirely.

Comment: When I search for performance_test_help in the code, i get no results... Still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` before running rake test. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Did you do rake db:migrate at first?

Comment: Yea, everything has been migrated over. This is driving me nuts